# calculation of divergence of a covariant vector

Tags: coordinate-systems, tensors

> $(x,y)$ are rectangular Cartesian coordinates in a plane and
> $(\bar{x},\bar{y})$ are coordinates defined by
> $$x=\frac{\bar{x}^2+\bar{y}^2}{2} \ \ , \ \ y=\bar{x}\bar{y}$$ If
> $A_1,A_2$ are coordinates of a covariant vector in the
> $\bar{x},\bar{y}$ coordinates defined by
> $A_1=A_2=(\bar{x}^2-\bar{y}^2)^2$ , show that its divergence is
> $$\frac{2(\bar{x}-\bar{y})^2}{\bar{x}+\bar{y}}$$

Clearly the metric tensor in the new coordinate is $$g_{11}=g_{22}=\bar{x}^2+\bar{y}^2$$ Hence the conjugate metric tensors are $$g^{11}=g^{22}=\frac{1}{\bar{x}^2+\bar{y}^2}$$ Hence $$\text{div}(A_i)=g^{ij}A_{i \ , \ j}=g^{11}A_{1,1}+g^{22}A_{2,2}$$ "$,$" is the covariant differentiation operator . So $$\text{div}(A_i)=g^{11}\bigg(\frac{\partial A_1}{\partial\bar{x}}-\Gamma^1_{11}A_1-\Gamma^2_{11}A_2\bigg)+g^{22}\bigg(\frac{\partial A_2}{\partial\bar{y}}-\Gamma^1_{22}A_1-\Gamma^2_{22}A_2\bigg)$$ But upon calculation of the Christoffel symbols and substituting in the expression gives $$\text{div}(A_i)=\frac{4(\bar{x}^2-\bar{y}^2)(\bar{x}-\bar{y})}{\bar{x}^2+\bar{y}^2}$$ I don't get what is going possibly wrong there , any help will be appreciated .

Comment: I suppose you have to take into consideration non-diagonal components of metric tensor, namely $g_{12}=2xy$ - thay are not zero in you case and contribute into calculations. $det|g_{ik}|={(x^2-y^2)}^2$

Comment: But $g_{xy}=g_{yx}=0$ in Cartesian coordinates , therefore $g_{ij}=\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial x^l}{\partial x^j}g_{kl}$ with $g_{kl}$ identified as $g_{xy},g_{yx}$ should make $g_{12},g_{21}=0$ .

Comment: yes, if you go to $g_{iJ}$ via transformation of $g=diag(1,1)$, you get non-diagonal component: $g_{12}=(\frac{d}{d\bar{x}}x)(\frac{d}{d\bar{y}}x)+(\frac{d}{d\bar{x}}y)(\frac{d}{d\bar{y}}y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already correctly calculated $g_{11}$ and $g_{22}$ of metric tensor $g_{ik}$. The non-diagonal component $g_{12}=g_{21}=2xy$ (to save time I don't write barr above x and y). $G=det|g_{ik}|=(x^2-y^2)^2$, $A^1=A^2=x^2+y^2-2xy$ $(A^1=g^{11}A_1+g^{12}A_2)$. Then you can calculate Christoffel symbols (from learning point this is a good approach), but let me go directly to the goal: in case of divergence of a vector we may use the formula for $A_{i;j}g^{ij}$ (; means covariant differentiation): $A_{i;j}g^{ij}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{G}}\frac{d}{dx^i}(\sqrt{G}A^i)$(summation over repeated indexes i)$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{G}}\frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{G}A^1)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{G}}\frac{d}{dy}(\sqrt{G}A^2)=\frac{1}{x^2-y^2}\frac{d}{dx}\left((x^2-y^2)(x-y)^2\right)+\frac{1}{x^2-y^2}\frac{d}{dy}\left((x^2-y^2)(x-y)^2\right)=2\frac{(x-y)^3}{x+y}$

Hopefully this will be helpful.